# Visual Studio Windows Form - pass data from seperate form (not parent) to Child MDI

Tags: windows, forms, visual-studio, parent-child, mdi

Ive searched and searched but cannot find the answer to this question.

How do I pass data from a form that is not a parent to a child MDI in visual studio windows form.

Scenario:-

Parent has a menu tree, the menu is clicked opening up a child form, within this form there is a button which opens a separate form that has a databound listbox.
I am trying to  pass data from this separate form (a selected item on the listbox to be precise) to a text box on the child form.

All I can seem to find is how to pass data between parent and child and visa versa.

I would really appreciate some examples.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the sub form modal or not?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a good thing you couldn't find this, as a lot of the solutions out there are naff.

The quick and not too horrible way

Define an interface

e.g

```
public interface IOwnerValue
{
String SomeValue {get;set;}
}
```

Add it to your Child form and implement it
e.g.

```
public class ChildForm : Form, IOwnerValue
{

public String SomeValue
{
get {return SomeTextBox.Text;}
set {SomeTextBox.Text = value;}
}
}
```

Then overload the subform's constructor to take an argument of IChildValue.
and add a private member to hold it.
e.g

```
private IOwnerValue _childValue;

Public MySubForm(IOwnerValue argValue) :base()
{
   _childValue = argValue;
}
```

Then in your button click handler

say
using (MySubForm f = new Subform(this))
{
   f.ShowDialog();
}

Then when you want to set the value in the
It's just something like

```
if (_childValue != null)
{
_childValue.SomeValue =  SomeStringFromSomewhere;
}
```

You could skip the interface, but then you'd have to tightly couple the ChildForm and Subform classes. Imagine if you wanted to reuse the subform for a different type of child form, or have a different subform that did something similar. The interface lets you keep things decoupled, not to mention write a unit test or two.

Another way though is to move all this to a separate class where both forms have a reference to it's interface. One sets the property. it has an "Onchanged" event. the form that's interested in it registers an event handler. That would be a bit over the top for one text value, between two forms though.

Whatever way you go if it has something like

```
TheFormThatCreatedMe.SomeTextBox.Text = SomeString;
```

Run away screaming.

Comment: Hi Tony, really really appreciate your answer and your swift response. I can see what it achieves however im struggling to implement it as I'm using visual studio windows form and the code you have used is .net?? (maybe) lol. Pushing my luck but is there any chance you could edit this for visual basic. Once again, thanks in advance.

Comment: Well I figure you can manage assignment and such. VB.Net and interfaces is here . http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6x8ydw5(v=vs.71).aspx